# Share a widget in multiple windows Tcl/Tk

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

Let's say I have a `label` widget `.x.somelabel`. Is there a way to insert this label in multiple different windows, so it can be shared between them? I tried to use `grid` with `-in` options, but it looks like it inserts the `label` in the widget that is specified last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't share the label widget itself.

But you can share the variable the labels are using to display the text.

```
 package require Tk

 set vars(statusmessage) "All is ok on the western front."

 toplevel .x
 ttk::label .x.somelabel -textvariable vars(statusmessage)
 pack .x.somelabel

 toplevel .y
 ttk::label .y.msglabel -textvariable vars(statusmessage)
 pack .y.msglabel

 # Change the variable after one second
 after 1000 [list set vars(statusmessage) {Error!}]
```